# Почему не работает grid в media

Tags: css

Не работает grid в media почему ?

```css
body{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
   'header header header'
   'article Nav ads'
  'footer footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 256px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

#pageHeader{
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: gold; 
  
}
#mainArticle{
   grid-area: article;
   background-color: gold; 
}
#mainNav{
  grid-area: Nav;
   background-color: gold; 

}
#siteAds{
  grid-area: ads;
   background-color: gold; 
    
}
#pageFooter{
  grid-area: footer;
   background-color: gold; 
   
}
  @media all and (max-width: 575px){
  body {
  grid-template-areas:
    'header'
    'article'
    'ads'
    'nav'
    'footer';
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
};
```

```html
<header id=pageHeader>
 header
</header>
<article id=mainArticle>
article
</article>
<nav id=mainNav>
nav
</nav>
<div id=siteAds>
Ads
</div>
<footer id=pageFooter>
footer
</footer>
```